# Implementing Pagination with Preserved Filtering Parameters in ASP.NET Core MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am writing an ASP.NET Core mvc project using an open source api. The API returns the following information: list of movies found(docs), total number of movies(total), number of movies on the current page(limit), number of pages(pages), current page(page).

```
public record MovieViewModel()
{
    public List<Movie> docs { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }
    public MovieFilters movieFilters { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently trying to implement movie filtering by some parameters (the api supports filtering and returns filtered data), but I have a problem with implementing pagination between this data.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchByFilters(List<string> selectedGenres, List<string> selectedCountries, List<string> selectedYears, int page = 1)
    {
        MovieFilters filters = new MovieFilters();
        filters.Countries = selectedCountries;
        filters.Genres = selectedGenres;
        filters.Years = selectedYears;
        
        var dataFromApi = await _kinopoiskApiService.GetMoviesByFilter(filters, page);
        
        MovieViewModel? movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieViewModel>(dataFromApi);
        if (movies == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        
        movies.MovieFilters = filters;
        
        return View(movies);
    }
```

My first version of the pagination looked like this:

```
<li class="page-item @(Model.page >= Model.pages ? "disabled" : "")">
    <a class="page-link" href="?page=@(Model.page + 1)">Next</a>
</li>
```

But in this case, all filtering parameters are deselected and an empty list is passed for the next page.

Then I tried the next option:

```
<li class="page-item @(Model.page >= Model.pages ? "disabled" : "")">
    <a 
        class="page-link" 
        asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SearchByFilters"
        asp-route-page="@Model.page+1" 
        asp-route-selectedCountries="@Model.MovieFilters.Countries"
        asp-route-selectedGenres="@Model.MovieFilters.Genres">Next
    </a>
</li>
```

But in this case, the parameters are passed incorrectly.

Could you please tell me how to implement pagination correctly to preserve the filtering parameters?

Comment: `Model.MovieFilters.Countries` is an array of strings, the default behaviour would be to use the built-in ToString() which will return something like `System.String[]`, same applies to Geners

Comment: @user1406062, Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: think about it this way, you want to pass the filter to the view so it can be sent back to the controller when clicking on next page, so try to serialize the filters, or store them in session, if list of Countries is Brazil and Spain, then convert the list to string, something like `['Brazil','Spain']` and here you can pass it and get it back, but everytime you need to convert to string then parse from string to object. Not effecient, but worked with me